# How to paginate in Firebase Database #AskFirebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am creating an application that is some kind of a personal vocabulary. The database is of the following form.

Now I need to **implement a pagination**, partial retrieval of the words of a user, but **preserving the lexicographical order**. Keeping words as keys (`/user/{uid}/words/{word}`) is not suitable, because handling homographs will be impossible in the future (as their key will coincide). I decided to keep additional property `word` for each user, so that I can call `db.getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("words").orderByChild("word")`.

This will retrieve all words of a user. Now I need to paginate this query, e.g. first download 20 words and then again 20 etc., but preserving lexicographical order.

```
{
  "users" : {
    "yXYSqB016JMr1FIc85pvMbvqDDt2" : {
      "words" : {
        "5v1a1PaDKnTvvOH19kaFTa1iyOx2" : {
          "index" : 1,
          "word" : "apple"
        },
        "kXHakBKxk9TrAlWL1vTOCe0akk80" : {
          "index" : 2,
          "word" : "house"
        },
        "xSKSqB312JMrsFig15pvMbvqAAt0" : { ... }
      }
    },
    "zCAtMpl9uxSjG9dJarGktTTs20w2" : { ... }
  },
  "vocabulary" : {
    "en" : {
      "5v1a1PaDKnTvvOH19kaFTa1iyOx2" : {
        "definitions" : {
          "a fruit that grows on a tree" : true
        },
        "word" : "apple"
      },
      "kXHakBKxk9TrAlWL1vTOCe0akk80" : { ... },
      "xSKSqB312JMrsFig15pvMbvqAAt0" : { ... }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Answer below. For future questions: Please don't post JSON screenshot, but post the JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to come from a SQL way of thinking, where you paginate by specifying the number of items to get and *the number of items to skip*. This is index-based pagination.

Firebase on the other uses cursor-based pagination. You tell it the nimber of items to get and at *which item to start (or end)*. You identify this item by the value of the property on which you order, in your case that is the value of `word`. Since the same value could potentially appear in multiple children, you can also specify the key (the thing starting with `5v1a1...`) of the child at which to start/end as a second parameter.

So say that you have a page size of two. You get the first 2 words with:

```
DatabaseReference allWords = db.getReference().child("users").child(uid).child("words");
Query firstPage = allWords.orderByChild("word").limitToFirst(2);
```

When you attach a listener to this, you'll get the first two words. You'll need to remember the `word` and the key of the last word in this first page:

```
String lastWordOnPreviousPage = "house";
String lastKeyOnPreviousPage = "5v1a1...";
```

Now if you need the second page of two words, you get them by:

```
Query secondPage = allWords.orderByChild("word").startAt(lastWordOnPreviousPage, lastKeyOnPreviousPage).limitToFirst(2);
```